# Modifying matplotlib checkbutton

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote a code to display live feed of analog data. The code uses pyfirmata to define pins and pull readings. I've set the funcanimation to pull all 12 channels when the port is open. Currently, matplotlib checkbutton is used to show/hide live feed of the channels.

I'd like to manipulate the matplotlib checkbutton so that only the channels that are checked are actually read instead of just being hidden.

The matplotlib widget module is a little too sophisticated for me to break down to a level where I can modify it. What I'd like to do is write a true/false status on each index depending on its visibility then put a nested if statements in the funcanimation to *read* only the visible lines. I'd appreciate if anyone could share me a sample code to allow me to do that.

Here is a segment of my code:

```
##check buttons
lines = [ln0, ln1, ln2, ln3, ln4, ln5, ln6, ln7, ln8, ln9, ln10, ln11]
labels = [str(ln0.get_label()) for ln0 in lines]
visibility = [ln0.get_visible() for ln0 in lines]
check = CheckButtons(ax1, labels, visibility)
for i, c in enumerate(colour):
    check.labels[i].set_color(c)

def func(label):
    index = labels.index(label)
    lines[index].set_visible(not lines[index].get_visible())

check.on_clicked(func)

## define pins
a0 = due.get_pin('a:0:i')
a1 = due.get_pin('a:1:i') 
a2 = due.get_pin('a:2:i')
a3 = ...

##funcanimation
def rt(i):
    t.append(datetime.now())
    if due.is_open == True:
            T0.append(round(a0.read()*3.3/0.005, 1))
            T1.append(round(a1.read()*3.3/0.005, 1))
            ...
```

Here is the graph and checkbuttons when run:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtuaj.jpg)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There is a get_status function embedded in the matplotlib widget which returns a tuple of trues and falses to indicate the status of check buttons. I used this to write a nested if statements in the funcanimation so that only checked ones are read.